# calculating weekly count down for a given date in SSIS

Tags: ssis, etl

I need to get the count down of the week numbers for a given date.

For example data is '2018/10/01/' then it should show the current week as week '-7'. and so on till its week 0 which is the week of 2018/10/01 and then i need count the weeks from that date like +1 week so on on SSIS.

Please help me.

Comment: In which language do you want to make this? Does it have to be an expression in visual studio or do you want it in a specific language? Hint: It has something to do with converting to iso week numbers and then applying basic math

Comment: does -7 mean that we are 7 weeks until 10/1/2018?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in a derived column.

```
(DT_I4)(  datediff("dd",startdate,enddate) / 7)
```

This will currently round to closest int.

There are other options like FLOOR() or CEILING() that can adjust the result differently.